# What is the difference between scanf("%d", *p) and scanf("%d", p)?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dereference

Pointers are a new thing for me and I'm struggling to understand it, but I won't give in and hopefully learn it.

What would be the difference between `scanf ("%d", *p)` and `scanf ("%d", p)`?

In examples I saw that if I want to input some value in a variable, I should use `scanf ("%d", p)`. That doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't it be `scanf ("%d", *p)`?

I interpret it as: "put some integer value where the pointer is pointing" and for instance it is pointing on variable `x` and then it should be `x = 10`, but it isn't. And how then to use `scanf()` and pointers to set values in an array?

Where and what am I getting wrong? I'm trying to learn this using C language, since it is the one which I'm supposed to use in my class.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    float x[10], *p;
    int i;
    p = &x[0];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf("%d", p + i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d", *(p + i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why is only `p + i` in the first `for () {}` and `*(p + i)` in the second loop? I would put `*(p + i)` also in the first `for () {}`. `*(p + i)` to me is like: "to what the (p+i)th element is and make it equal some value".

Comment: Perhaps you should add types...

Comment: What is `p`? If `p` isn't a pointer, you should use `scanf ("%d", &p)`

Comment: BTW: Check the return value of `scanf()` before using what was hopefully read.  `scanf("%d", p + i) != 1) Oops();`

Comment: If `p` is a pointer, then the value of `p` is "where the pointer is pointing".  `*p` would be "the thing being pointed to".

Comment: `scanf("%d", &x[i]);` would be easier to write and understand

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`*p` means go to the place `p` points to
`&p` means take the address of `p`, or "get a pointer to" `p`

```
int i;
scanf("%d", &i); // gives scanf a pointer to i

int i;
int *p = &i;
scanf("%d", p); // a more contrived way to say the same thing
```

The obligatory visual explanation is [Pointer Fun with Binky](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-pJlnpkLp0).

You can read the types from right to left:

`int *p` => "`p` has type `int *`" => `p` is a pointer to an `int`
`int *p` => "`*p` has type `int`" => `*p` is the `int` pointed to by `p`

Answer (score 12):

One is right, the other is wrong. (Or both may be wrong, depending on what `p` is.)

If you call

```
scanf("%d", SOMETHING);
```

then `SOMETHING` *must* be a pointer to an `int`.

If you have an `int` object, use unary `&` to get its address (i.e., a pointer to the object):

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
```

If `p` happens to be an `int*`, then you can use its value:

```
int *p;
scanf("%d", p);
```

But here I haven't assigned a value to `p`, so this compiles but has undefined behavior. This is ok:

```
int n;
int *p = &n;
scanf("%d", p);
```

As for using `*p`, that would be valid only if `p` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`:

```
int n;
int *p0 = &n;
int **p = &p0;
scanf("%d", *p);
```

But it would rarely make sense to do that. The vast majority of the time, the argument is going to be simply the address of some `int` object, like `&n`.

If `n` is an int, then just passing `n` to `scanf` wouldn't make sense. You'd merely be passing the current *value* of `n`. The point is that you want to permit `scanf` to store a new value in `n`, and to do that, `scanf` need's the address of `n`.

Answer (score 2):

Function calls in C pass arguments by value, not by reference.  This means that when you call a function with arguments, the function receives *copies* of the arguments, and that function cannot directly modify the original arguments from the callsite.  That is:

```
int x = 42;
foo(x);
printf("%d\n", x);
```

`foo` cannot change the variable `x`, and the code will always print `42`.

But there are many cases where a function might want to modify the arguments from the caller. `scanf` is one such case.  To accomplish this, these functions require using *a level of indirection*.  Instead of passing the variable to be modified directly to the function, the caller instead passes a pointer to that variable.  The function then receives a copy of the pointer, and by dereferencing it, can access and can modify the variable it's pointing to.

I recommend spending some time reading the comp.lang.c FAQ.  This topic is discussed in:

- [12.12a Why doesn't the call `scanf("%d", i)` work?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1.html)
- [12.12b Why does the call `scanf("%s", s)` work?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1a.html)

Answer (score 1):

If *p* is the variable (say, an int), you would use **&p** to pass its pointer to scanf. *p* alone is not a pointer, and *p compounds the problem.